# Nexus Setup in Kubernetes for Docker Hub Caching via Traefik IngressRoute

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nexus, traefik

I'm currently facing a challenge with setting up Nexus in a Kubernetes environment to cache Docker Hub using a Traefik IngressRoute, and I'm reaching out for some expert advice.
My primary issue is that when I execute the docker pull ubuntu command, the images are not being cached. Specifically, I don't see any data in the [repository I created for Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOTK.png).

Here are my manifests files:

`nx-deploy.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nexus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nexus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nexus
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nexus
        image: sonatype/nexus3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "2000m"
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "4000m"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nexus-data
          mountPath: /nexus-data
      volumes:
      - name: nexus-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nexus-data
```

`nx-service.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nexus-service
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
  selector:
    app: nexus
```

`ingress.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute 
metadata:
  name: nexus
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`nexus.example.io`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
    kind: Rule 
    services:
    - name: nexus-service
      port: 80
```

`nx-pvc.yml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nexus-data
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

I've configured Nexus for anonymous access without specifying HTTP/HTTPS protocols. In my setup, Traefik listens on port 80, and the Kubernetes service redirects from port 80 to port 8081 in the Nexus pod. The `nx-deploy.yml` for Nexus has port 8081 open.

On the client machine, I've modified the `daemon.json` file with the following entries:

```json
"insecure-registries": ["nexus.example.io"],
"registry-mirrors": ["http://nexus.example.io"]
```

Additionally, I've updated the `/etc/hosts` file to include the IP address of the machine where Kubernetes is running and my DNS nexus.example.io.

I'm wondering what I might be missing or if there are any specific configurations or steps I've overlooked. Any guidance or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you did not create any connector for your docker registry. How do you intend to join it then? Docker registries are not accessed from your client like the other "regular" nexus repositories (on default nexus http(s) port). You need a specific port, either secured or not depending on your current nexus setup. In you current setup, that means you need to open a second port on your container and add an other route which will direct requests from your docker client to the correct registry port.

Comment: @Zeitounator Hi! I configured the connector, created 2 services, and opened two ports in Traefik, and everything started working. Thank you so much for your help!